# Передача переменной через AJAX magnificPopup

Tags: javascript, ajax

В окне magnificPopup через AJAX мне необходимо передать переменную, исходя из документации и поиска по интернету достиг следующего кода:

```
$('.link_popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',

  ajax: {
    settings: {
      cache:false, 
      data: { 
        'route_name': 'zZzzzz',
      }
    },

    cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur', // CSS class that will be added to body during the loading (adds "progress" cursor)
    tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.' //  Error message, can contain %curr% and %total% tags if gallery is enabled
  },

});
```

Но, переменная не передается

Принимаю соответственно следующим образом:

```
if ( $_POST ) {
    $route_name = $_POST["route_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решается добавлением метода в параметры

```
$('.link_popup').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax',

  ajax: {
    settings: {
      method: "POST",
      cache: false, 
      data: { 
        'route_name': 'Zzzz',
      }
    },

    cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur', // CSS class that will be added to body during the loading (adds "progress" cursor)
    tError: '<a href="%url%">The content</a> could not be loaded.' //  Error message, can contain %curr% and %total% tags if gallery is enabled
  },

});
```